# Removing parenthesis in elisp

Tags: string, elisp

I'd like to extract a repeating string to a variable.

```
;; following code works, but I want to replace "~/+NOTES/ztd/" by a variable

(setq org-capture-templates '(
    ("c" "Capture" entry (file+headline "~/+NOTES/ztd/murmur.org" "Capture")
         "* %u %? " :prepend t)
))
```

However, a naive try does not work. It does not lead to an error immediately, but it works differently from my expectation.

```
;;; code fails.. need to be fixed

(defvar org-gtd-directory "~/+NOTES/ztd/")
(setq org-capture-templates '(
    ("c" "Capture" entry (file+headline (concat org-gtd-directory "murmur.org") "Capture")
         "* %u %? " :prepend t)
))
```

#### Question

I thought  `(concat org-gtd-directory "murmur.org")` exactly should be `"~/+NOTES/ztd/murmur.org"`, but it's not. Which part did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

[`quote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) prevents evaluation.
Use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) instead:

```lisp
(defvar org-gtd-directory "~/+NOTES/ztd/")
(setq org-capture-templates `(
    ("c" "Capture" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-gtd-directory "murmur.org") "Capture")
         "* %u %? " :prepend t)
))
```